# @EnableSwagger - can't resolve in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0

Spring boot

in build.gradle:

```
  dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    implementation 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0')
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0')
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.8.0'
```

In my entry point:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

import java.util.Date;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableSwagger
public class EshopApplication {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(EshopApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        SpringApplication.run(EshopApplication.class, args);
    }
```

But I get compile error:

**cannot find symbol class EnableSwagger**

```
@EnableSwagger
 ^
  symbol: class EnableSwagger
```

Comment: Try @EnableSwagger2

Comment: @Jens I got error: package springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations does not exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `@EnableSwagger2`, and keep the same version of dependencies for `springfox-swagger2` and `springfox-swagger-ui`

```
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'
```

And finally, refresh the Gradle

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Error: package springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations does not exist

Comment: Refresh your Gradle project

Comment: That's strange, in my gradle project. I did exactly the same.  `compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'` & `compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'`